# why RestSharp Request method Change from POST to GET?

Tags: c#, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I am using RestSharp to post some data to a url. I am monitoring this operation using fiddler. when I use Simple .net **HttpClient** with this code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>  {
                { "par1", "1395/11/29" },
                { "par2", "2" }};
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://someurl.com/resource", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

every thing is good and this return true result. but when i try to use **RestSharp** with this code:

```
 RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestSharp.RestRequest("/resource");
 request.AddParameter("par1", val, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
 request.AddParameter("par2", val, RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
 request.AddHeader("Origin", "http://someurl.com");
 request.Method = RestSharp.Method.POST;
 RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient("http://someurl.com");
 var response = client.Execute(request);
```

then fiddler show me the request sent by GET method instead of POST?

I check another time my fiddler and found this issue:

> Content-Type: par1

why this is happening for me?

Comment: this was a silly mistake. i was using "http" insteade of "https" and this was not handled in remote host. :)

Comment: Expierenced similar problem on a REST api that had been working earlier, In my case I had to add "www". Probably changes on the default settings settings on endpoint part

Answer (score 0):

Change your ParameterType argument to **GetOrPost** and it will work

```
request.AddParameter("par1", val, RestSharp.ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("par2", val, RestSharp.ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

Comment: i do this but no change happened and my request monitor as GET

Answer (score 0):

1. **Initialize Request as POST with JSON.**

   var client = new RestClient(PreUri);

   var request = new RestRequest(Uri, Method.POST) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
2. **Add object in body**

   request.AddBody(obj);
3. **Execute**

   var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

   var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

Comment: i must send data to server in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format

Answer (score 0):

May be you call "client.Get" instead of "client.Post".

```
var client = new RestClient("https://someservice.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/token/", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json).AddJsonBody(SomeObject);
var response = client.Get(request);
```

You may expect this code to make POST request. Because the methos is specified as **Method.POST**.
But **NO**. It will not. Because after calling **client.Get(request)**; This changes the metod to **GET**.
So, the right way to use **POST** request is like follows:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://someservice.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/token/", DataFormat.Json).AddJsonBody(SomeObject);
var response = client.Post(request);
```

Comment: please don't write posts in first person, it makes it seem like your the OP on a puppet account